# sql distinct count php

Tags: php, sql, count

I'm new to using Distinct in SQL together with PHP.

```
$sqlcount="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ppo) AS NumberOfRows FROM projectcostingfile
WHERE pcode='".$pcode1."'"; 
$resultcount =  mysqli_query($conn,$sqlcount);
$rowcount = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcount);
echo $rowcount['NumberOfRows'];
```

Like to check what is wrong with this code. It is not echoing.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: Can you show us the rows of that table you're trying to query?